# Overwrite current output in the R console

Tags: r, date, time, console

I have been playing around with the R function txtProgressBar().  How can I hijack the function's ability to overwrite the current output in the console?

i.e. the progress bar updates like this:

```
> some R function
============
```

becomes

```
> some R function
========================
```

NOT

```
> some R function
============
========================
```

For example, how do I write function that will display the current time in the console:

```
> some R function
13:01
```

becomes

```
> some R function
13:02
```

NOT

```
> some R function
13:01
13:01
13:01
13:01
13:02
13:02
13:02
13:02
```

Comment: Answers discussed further on my blog.  Shameless self-promo: http://4dpiecharts.com/2011/05/11/a-clock-utility-via-console-hackery/

Comment: Nowadays, the package [progress](https://github.com/r-lib/progress/) may also be an option to display nicely formatted and customizable progress bars.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This program seems to work:

```
while (1) {
cat('\b\b\b\b\b\b',format(Sys.time(),'%H:%M'))
flush.console() 
}
```

Are there any reasons this might be a bad idea?

/edit: even better (thanks @Greg Snow):

```
while (1) {
cat('\r',format(Sys.time(),'%H:%M:%S'))
flush.console() 
}
```

Comment: The \b backslash character can cause issues with programs that capture console output (such as TextMate and SublimeText).  What happens is that the output looks like this:   

(0 tests)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b(1 test)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b         \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b...(99 tests)\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b
No solution I've found ATM, just something to keep in mind if you plan to release your work for others' use

Comment: @Zach I don't know, I only noticed the \b issue when it became a problem with something I was using

Answer (score 23):

Instead of "\b\b\b\b" you can just use "\r" to go to the beginning of the line and overwrite everything on the line (make sure to still use cat and don't put in a line feed).

Though if you want to display progress it might be better to use winProgressBar (windows only) or tkProgressBar (tcltk package, all platforms) which can be updated with a label in addition to the progress bar.

On windows you can also use the setWindowTitle or setStatusBar functions to put that type of information into the top or bottom of the larger window.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can:

```
while(1) {
  cat("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b",format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S"),sep="")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to use the function `message` to print something, you can set its parameter `appendLF` to FALSE to avoid it printing a new line and then the use the carriage return `('\r')` character to return to the start of the line, for example:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
  message('\r', i, appendLF = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, however it leaves some "residue" characters in the console, when shorter strings are passed after longer ones:
`m = c('Test', 'Test2', 'Test very long string', 'Short Test');
for (i in m) {
  Sys.sleep(0.3);
  message('\r', i, appendLF = FALSE)
}`

Answer (score 1):

I do not think overwriting is possible on the console. There is no backspace escape sequence. The progress bar can be drawn because the cat function will not emit a `cr` unless told to do so.

Edit:
I was wrong. The backspace character is recognized:

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
     cat(as.character(Sys.time())) 
     flush.console() 
     for(i in 1:19) {cat("\8")} }
```

Comment: Gotcha.  So I can print `13:01` and update it to `13:01 13:02` but not `13:02`?