# Creating a progress update by replacing output in the R console from C/C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Is it possible to overwrite R console output with the C/C++ print functions for R?

```
Rcpp::sourceCpp( code = '
  #include <Rcpp.h>

  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  void print_test() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      std::stringstream strs;
      strs << "number: " << i;
      std::string temp_str = strs.str();
      char const* char_type = temp_str.c_str();      

      REprintf(char_type);
    }
  }'
)

print_test()
```

The output of this function is

```
number: 0number: 1number: 2number: 3number: 4number: 5number: 6number: 7number: 8number: 9
```

but I want it to be a dynamic sequence. For example:

```
number: 0
```

Wait a few seconds:

```
number: 1
```

where `number: 0` is completely erased from the console. This procedure repeats until `number: 9` is reached.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953718/overwrite-current-output-in-the-r-console) question, but I was not able to get the carriage return solution to work with REprintf().

Comment: You have that backwards. _When called from R_ we are only allowed to use R's output facilties.  A CRAN package would *never* be allowed to overwrite R's internal output.

Comment: I feel that this is likely missing something in `Rinterfaces.h` (`R_FlushConsole()`) in a way similar to a progress bar update. So, maybe checkout [`RcppProgress`](https://github.com/kforner/rcpp_progress)

Comment: So yes, "feeding it" strings is fine, "overwrite" as your title suggests is not.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @coatless Thanks for improving my question. Funny that you mention RcppProgress, because I'm asking this question exactly to [add functionality to this package](https://github.com/kforner/rcpp_progress/issues/11).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the proper updates to the *R* console, you will need to use the [`Rinterfaces.h`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/RHOME/doc/manual/R-exts.html#Setting-R-callbacks) header. This header is only available for unix-alike systems. Thus, your progress update will *break* on Windows.

In particular, you should use `REprintf` (standard error) or `Rprintf` (standard output) in combination with `R_FlushConsole` to update the console. The key here is to surround output with `"\r"` or a carriage return, which forces a return to the beginning of the line. This will cause your value to be printed and then the previous line to be "erased."

During this procedure, it may be advantageous to check for user interrupts (e.g. if user presses escape, exit the process). Thus, I've included a call to `R_CheckUserInterrupt()`.

Lastly, to emphasize an update is happening, I've opted to *slow* the loop by forcing it to sleep every second or so.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// for unix-alike machines only
#if !defined(WIN32) && !defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__WIN32__)
#include <unistd.h>
#include <Rinterface.h>
#endif

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void print_test() {
  int n = 10;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    #if !defined(WIN32) && !defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__WIN32__)
    // Sleep for a second
    usleep(1000000);
    #endif

    std::stringstream strs;
    strs << "number: " << i;
    std::string temp_str = strs.str();
    char const* char_type = temp_str.c_str();      

    REprintf("\r");
    REprintf("%s", char_type);
    REprintf("\r");
    #if !defined(WIN32) && !defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__WIN32__)
    R_FlushConsole();
    #endif
    R_CheckUserInterrupt();
  }

}
```

Example:

[image: Progress Update]

Comment: Excellent! That works exactly as expected. But: are you sure that there is no platform independent solution?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.