# Printing a message to R console from package in c++

Tags: c++, r

I am trying to debug an R package programmed in C++, and I need to print a variable to the R console. My knowledge of C++ is somewhat limited and I have no prior experience with linking C++ with R.

`cout` does not work. I have tried several options described here but none seem to work, the console remains silent. In particular, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623478/creating-a-progress-update-by-replacing-output-in-the-r-console-from-c-c) answer.

Comment: If you are using [tag:rcpp], this might be of use: https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcout/

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Is there an option without Rcpp?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but apparently it's REprintf? [Creating a progress update by replacing output in the R console from C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623478/creating-a-progress-update-by-replacing-output-in-the-r-console-from-c-c)

Comment: I tried that answer and does not work for me...

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? Did you include a trailing newline for Rprintf [as recommended by the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Printing)?

Comment: @Botje,  I gave that answer a second chance and I was lacking a library, it is now working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nice! Next time please be more precise than "does not work", it will save everyone some trouble.