# Printing multiple lines of text in console by replacing old lines

Tags: r

I want to print **three** lines of text to the console replacing the current three lines that are printed. The solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953718/overwrite-current-output-in-the-r-console) do not work for **three** lines.

I want this output for every iteration:

Line1

Line2

Line3

I tried the following:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  cat('\rLine1', '\rLine2', '\rLine3')
}
```

Output: Line3

```
for(i in 1:3){
  cat('\rLine1', '\nLine2', '\nLine3')
}
```

Ouput:

Line1

Line2

Line1

Line2

Line1

Line2

Line3

```
for(i in 1:3){
  cat('\rLine1', 'Line2', 'Line3')
}
```

Output: Line1 Line2 Line3 Line2 Line3

Note that the acutall text is different and not line1, line2 and line3 but it is actually progress of a function, the elasped and the predicted time, but all the variables are characters. See

```
cat('\rProgress: |',rep('=',floor((i/iterations)*50)),rep(' ',50 - floor((i/iterations)*50)),'|',
      'Elapsed time:', elapsedTime,
      'Time left:',    predictedTime,
      sep = '')
```

The actual code is too long and complex therefore I provided the example above. The desired output is

Progress: |====================                              |

Elapsed time:0 h, 0 min, 4 sec

Time left:0 h, 0 min, 10 sec

Comment: I still don't fully understand the problem. Maybe provide a small dataset with the expected output.

Comment: ... or at least the class of each element i.e. for `actually progress of a function`, `elasped time`and `predicted time`?

Comment: I added it. But the crucial things is that I want to print lines of text (characters) by replacing the current text in the console. I don't want to print new lines.

Comment: It's not because the soluations (e.g. \r) work only for one line. If you look at my solutions that would be clear.

Comment: Could `cat("\014") ` help? It clears the console.

Comment: I don't want to delete the whole console I want to replace the three lines that are printed in the console with three new lines.

Comment: Well, if you can emulate that by printing more than 3 lines.

Comment: I don't want to delete anything that has been previously printed by other functions. I just want to replace the output just created. Just like \r does for one line.

Comment: It is an interesting question. I don't know if there is a nice solution. A potential workaround is either `winProgressBar` or `tkProgressBar`, since they have `title` and `label` parameters which can be used to give additional information about the state of the running function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lines <- rep(c("Line1", "Line2", "Line3"), 3) # for 3 iterations
cat(lines, sep = "\n")
#output
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

Comment: Note that the acutall text is different and not lines but actually progress of a function, the elasped and the predicted time. I added this to the question, now, Sorry for being not acurrate enough.